# Orbits and Flows ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Suppose $ω(Γ) = \{x^∗\}$ is a single element set where $Γ$ is an orbit of a locally Lipschitz vector field $f \colon E → \mathbb R^n$ with $E ⊂ \mathbb R^n$ is open.

> **Question:**
>   Show that for $x ∈ Γ$, we have $φ_t(x) → x^∗$ as $t → ∞$, where $φ$ is the flow. Conclude that $x^∗$ is an equilibrium point.
>
> Hint: Assuming $φ_t(x)$ does not converge to $x^∗$, show that one can find $δ > 0$ such that the intersection of $Γ^+_x$ with the spheres $\{y∈\mathbb R^n :|y−x^∗|=δ\}$ is infinite.

The hint I was given confused me and not sure how to show the intersection of the orbit and sphere is infinite.

Comment: Spheres are compact.

Comment: I knew that spheres are compact but I am not understanding how the intersection is infinite when φt(x) does not converge to x*

Comment: Details in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed by contradiction: **Assume that there is no convergence to $x^*$.**

Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that the orbit $\varphi_t(x)$ intersects infinitely often the sphere of radius $\delta$ centered at $x^*$ (otherwise, for each $\delta$ the points $\varphi_t(x)$ would be inside the sphere for all sufficiently $t>T=T(\delta)$, but we are assuming that there is no convergence to $x^*$).

But since the sphere is compact there is an accumulation point and so a sequence $t_n\to+\infty$ such that that $\varphi_{t_n}(x)$ converges to some point $y$ on the sphere and so distinct from $x^*$. We know from the properties of the $\omega$-limit set that $y\in\omega(\Gamma)$, which gives a contradiction since $y\ne x^*$.

So there is convergence to $x^*$.